# comparison between unsigned int and unsigned char

Tags: c, type-conversion, unsigned-integer, unsigned-char, mplab

I have an unsigned char array, such as `Data[2]`. I needed it to compare with an output of a function returning unsigned int.

i tried to cast the `Data[2]` into unsigned int and vice versa. It didn't work.

What I am trying to do is:

```
if (Data[2] == ReadFlash2(40))
{
    //Do Something.
}
```

`ReadFlash2` is a function returning unsigned int, while `Data[2]` is a unsigned char.

I tried to cast each of them, but it didn't work.

Is there something I am doing wrong?  Which one should I cast, and to what should I cast it?

Thanks.

Edit:
the code for the Readflash function:

```
unsigned int ReadFlash2(unsigned int Addr) // use as Read Function 
{
pMem = (unsigned int*)MEM_STR_ADR; 
pMem += Addr; 
Nop(); 
return(*pMem); 
}
```

Comment: What is the error you are having?

Comment: @AlexandruBarbarosie, the `if` comparison is false, meaning it doesn't go through.

Comment: What is the value of `Data[2]` and the value of `ReadFlash2(40)`?

Comment: @Liban Are you sure that the numbers are equal?

Comment: @AlexandruBarbarosie, yes, in this case both contains `1`

Comment: @VaughnCato, `Data[2] = 1` and `ReadFlash(40)= 1`

Comment: @Liban that is what debugger told you? Or those are your own calculations?

Comment: @AlexandruBarbarosie, i checked each of the outputs separately. it is from the debugger.

Comment: What' the definition of Data look like? Just a wild guess, but are you working on a 16-bit MCU and trying to compare the whole two element array (not just a single element) to the int?

Comment: Here is an example that works: http://ideone.com/99b04Y  Can you provide a similarly simple example that doesn't work?

Comment: @Liban what do you mean by separatly? Please provide the code for the function and definition and assignment for the `Data` array. If bouth values are `1` it doesn't matter what data types those are the `if` statment should evaluate to `true`. If it evaluates to `false` you should look for the mistake somewhere else.

Comment: @jerry it is 32 bit PIC32MX795. the definition of Data looks like this: `unsigned char Data[30];`

Comment: There's something else going on. Can you reduce it down to an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) and post that? Is it MPLAB X or earlier? Which compiler?

Comment: @AlexandruBarbarosie i have just edited the question to include the ReadFlash2 function.

Comment: @jerry, i believe nothing else is going on, because if i remove the comparison, works perfect. i have also sent the two values to the host to check, and it is the same. so it have to do with `type`. it is MPLAB 8.89.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you are accessing volatile memory on the microcontroller, and this could be causing some confusion when debugging.  Try storing `Data[2]` and `ReadFlash(40)` into variables before the comparison:

```
unsigned char data_2 = Data[2];
unsigned int readflash2_40 = ReadFlash2(40);

if (data_2 == readflash2_40)
{
    //Do Something.
}
```

Now you should be able to inspect the actual values that are being compared by looking at the values in the variables.

Comment: i thought that too.. i did the same but still didn't work. to check whether the values are the same, i sent both of them to the host and it is the same.

Comment: Vaughn, the weird thing is: when i access directly `ReadFlash2(40)` it is `1`, but when i store into variable, it is `00`.

Comment: @Liban: Maybe the value changes.  Maybe when you were calling ReadFlash2(40) the first time to send it to the host, it was one value, and when you call it the next time to do the comparison it was a different value.

Comment: u were right the value was changing. there was something wrong with the flow of the program. and i cast both to `unsigned long`. it worked. thanks man.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't need to cast them at all, the rules in C relating to implicit promotions should take care of that for you.

In other words, comparing an `unsigned char` to an `unsigned int` will first promote the `unsigned char` to be compatible, *then* do the comparison.

It's all covered in C99 `6.3.1.8 Usual arithmetic conversions` which states (after discussing floating point types):

> Otherwise, the integer promotions are performed on both operands.
>
> Then the following rules are applied to the promoted operands:
>
> If both operands have the same type, then no further conversion is needed.
>
> Otherwise, if both operands have signed integer types or both have unsigned
>   integer types, the operand with the type of lesser integer conversion rank is
>   converted to the type of the operand with greater rank.

... and so on, but that last paragraph above is the applicable one.

If the types are as you've stated and `Data[2]` actually *is* the same value as what's returned from `ReadFlash2(40)`, then it's *not* a C environment, at least not according to the standard.

Comment: @Liban, well, it's either C or not C. If it's C, it will follow the rules. If it _doesn't_ follow the rules, it should be retagged as `close to C but not quite` :-)

Comment: so are you suggesting to promote the `unsigned char` to `unsigned int` ?

Comment: No, I'm suggesting it shouldn't be necessary, provided you have a real C environment. You could _try_ explicit promotion of the char and that may work but you're beyond my expertise there since I have little knowledge on non-conforming C-like environments :-)